# Hive database not working offline while works fine when connected to internet

Tags: database, flutter, dart, caching, flutter-hive

I am developing a flutter application in which I am implementing hive database for caching data.
I have added both `hive` `and hive_flutter` packages.
I am getting data from APIs and store that to hive to update data, It works fine when I used app connected to internet but didn't works when I try to read while being offline. Here is the code of my API method I am calling to get data:

```
static Future<List<UserPost>> getPosts() async {
    //I call my API in try block, if its successful, I update the data in hive
    List<UserPost> posts = [];
    Hive.openBox(Constants.APIDATA_BOX);
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'),);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Clear hive box from old data
      Hive.box(Constants.APIDATA_BOX).clear();
      Hive.box(Constants.APIDATA_BOX).put(Constants.API_DATA,jsonDecode(response.body));
    }
    } catch (e) {
      print('You are not connected to internet');
    }
    //I am getting data here from hive database and it works fine while connected to internet
    var listMaps =await Hive.box(Constants.APIDATA_BOX).get(Constants.API_DATA, defaultValue: []);
    posts = listMaps.map<UserPost>((map) {
       //Here flow stucked whenever working offline,
       //Data is also available but here conversion cause error, I have tried many way but fails.
       return UserPost.fromMap(map);
      }).toList();
  return posts;
  }
```

I don't why I am getting error, I have tried many conversion ways here but all works while being online. Any help will be highly apprerciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've understood the error but you should explain better which type of error you're having.
Anyway pay attention to the operations on Hive, which are often async, for example `Hive.openBox(Constants.APIDATA_BOX);`.

So when you have internet connection, you have to await for the response and Hive has time to open the box, otherwise it will throw an error so, considering the futures, you should do this:

```dart
static Future<List<UserPost>> getPosts() async {
    List<UserPost> posts = [];
    await Hive.openBox(Constants.APIDATA_BOX);
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'),);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      //Clear hive box from old data
      await Hive.box(Constants.APIDATA_BOX).clear();
      await Hive.box(Constants.APIDATA_BOX).put(Constants.API_DATA,jsonDecode(response.body));
    }
    } catch (e) {
      print('You are not connected to internet');
    }
    var listMaps = await Hive.box(Constants.APIDATA_BOX).get(Constants.API_DATA, defaultValue: []);
    posts = listMaps.map<UserPost>((map) {
       return UserPost.fromMap(map);
      }).toList();
    return posts;
  }
```

Note that `await Hive.put()` in a normal box is not strictly necessary, as explained in the [docs](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write?id=write)

Comment: This doesn't worked, i am not getting any error, i am also getting data printed on console but here in map method flow stucks and no data returns. 
```posts = listMaps.map<UserPost>((map) {
       return UserPost.fromMap(map);
      }).toList()
```
I have tried foreach loop here like this:
```for (var item in listMaps) {
        //Error occurs on below line
        posts.add(UserPost.fromMap(item));
        print('item Added to Post ');
    }```